# How can I add a line after every 10 records using MOD?

Tags: php

I am displaying records within a for loop. I want to add a new line to a table after every 10 columns using PHP's MOD function.

How can that be done?

I have tried the following

```
        $total_th = count($headers);

        $report_rows = '<thead><tr><th>Company Code</td>';
        foreach($headers AS $head){
            $report_rows .= '<th>'.$head['title'].'</th>';
        }   
        $report_rows .= '</tr></thead>';


        $total_results = count($results);

        $report_rows .= '<tbody>';


        for($i=0; $i< $total_results; ++$i){
        $row = $results[$i];

        //start new row
            if($i == 0 ||  $i % $total_th+1 == 0){
            $report_rows .= '<tr>';
            $report_rows .= '<td>'.$row['account_id'].'</td>';
            }

        //display all answers
        $report_rows .= '<td>'.$row['answer'].'</td>';

        //close row
            if( $i % $total_th+1 == 0){
            $report_rows .= '</tr>';
            }

        }
        //close tbody and table
        $report_rows .= '</tbody>';

echo '<table class="common2">';
echo $report_rows;
echo '</table>';
```