# How can I add a new row in a table every 10 columns automatically?

Tags: php, modulo

I have 2 queries that pull 2 different data set from the database
first one contains the header for a table so if the total results are 10 then we have 10 headers to the table.

the second one will have  records each with one value for each column. so if I have 5 records this means 5 x 10(total headers) = 50 records in the second dataset.

those 50 records I want to display it in the table.

My approach is to display one record at a time but after every 10 records close  and open a new  for the next row.

I am not sure if this is the best approach to this problem but I am open to better ideas.

Assuming my approach is a good approach, how can I create a new row in the table after every 10 records.

I have tried to acomplish this by using the Mod operation in PHP but this is not working for me.

Here is my current code that display data but it does not add  at the correct time/place.

My question is how to add fix this code to display the results correctly?

```
    //count of headers  
    $total_th = count($headers);

    //generate the headers
    $report_rows = '<thead><tr><th>Company Code</th>';
    foreach($headers AS $head){
        $report_rows .= '<th>'.$head['title'].'</th>';
    }   
    $report_rows .= '</tr></thead>';


    //count of the the actual results
    $total_results = count($results);

    //create the table body
    $report_rows .= '<tbody>';

    //loop all of the records
    for($i=0; $i< $total_results; ++$i){
    $row = $results[$i];

    //start new row "Add this only once per row
        if($i == 0 ||  $i % $total_th == 0){
        $report_rows .= '<tr>';
        $report_rows .= '<td>'.$row['company_code'].'</td>';
        }

    //display all answers
    $report_rows .= '<td>'.$row['answer'].'</td>';

    //close row if the $total_th is reached 
        if( $i % $total_th == 0){
        $report_rows .= '</tr>';
        }

    }
    //close tbody and table
    $report_rows .= '</tbody>';

echo '<table class="common2">';
echo $report_rows;
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: How is the loop going?

Comment: It's really easy, please show that you've made some attempt before coming here.

Comment: @Barmar i just update my question with my attempt

Comment: You are using `table`. Where you gonna put `hr`?

Comment: I said original <hr /> to make the question easier but it is <tr> new row in the table.

Comment: Please don't repost the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355623/how-can-i-add-a-line-after-every-10-records-using-mod

Comment: @andrewsi ....you linked to this question

Comment: I have send a flag for the Admin to delete the other question as it was not very clear on the need.

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 - *whistles innocently*

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364 do you remember your username ? :P

Comment: @karthikr thats a silly question.. i have a hard enough time remembering to put my pants on in the morning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [modulus operation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

```
$i = 1;
foreach($records as $record){
echo $record;
if ($i % 10 == 0)
   echo '<hr />';
$i++;
}
```

Comment: for some reason it is now working for me. Please review my post as I have modified it.