# Having issue in my for loop using PHP, I want to create dynamic rows and column in PHP, Each row has 10 column

Tags: php, loops, for-loop

I am Having an issue in my for loop using PHP, I want to create dynamic row and column, Each row has 10 column after 10 column, the second row also  end with 10 column like this up to 5 row, how to do It for a loop.

```
My for loop code:

    <table width="100%" border="1">
    <?php
    for($i=1; $i<=72; $i++)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td width="100%">
    <?php echo "Click Here to see Site No.'".$i."'. & Area sqft No" .$i;?></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

I tried like this also

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=72; $i++)
{
$x = 10; 
if ($i % $x == 0) 
{ 
?>
<td><?php echo $i;?></td>
<?php
}
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: you should use % module to determinate when reach every 10 loops. (if $i%10 == 0){ //do something }

Comment: kindly send me code , I am unable to slove this past three hours spent on this, look my expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I add a new row in a table every 10 columns automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373050/how-can-i-add-a-new-row-in-a-table-every-10-columns-automatically)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per what I understand you want simple 10 column in each row.

Here is my code which may help you:

```
     <table style="border:1px solid #000">

   
    
             <tr>
        <?php $t=1; for($k=1;$k<=72;$k++){?>
            <?php if($t == 10) { $t=0;?><td style="border:1px solid #000"> <?php echo $k; ?> </tr><?php } else  {?><td style="border:1px solid #000"> <?php echo $k; ?></td><?php } ?>
        <?php $t++;}?>
```

Comment: Hi after 10 column a new should with 11 to 20 after 20 column a new row should start with 21 , like 1 to 72 column to column i need is 72...each row has 10 column so that i will be end by 72 , change the code please

Comment: where to put if condition

Comment: i added if condition ,  <table style="border:1px solid #000">

         <?php 
   for($i=1;$i<72;$i++) 
   {
    ?>
               
               <tr>
                   <td style="border:1px solid #000"> <?php echo $i; ?>
                   
                   </td>
                   </tr>
                      <?php if($i%10==0){
        ?>
                         <td style="border:1px solid #000"> <?php echo $i; ?>
                        </td>
        <?php }?>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </table>  it is coming in only one column wise now row and column

Comment: Please check with this

 <table style="border:1px solid #000">
    
       
        
                 <tr>
            <?php $t=1; for($k=1;$k<=72;$k++){?>
                <?php if($t == 10) { $t=0;?><td style="border:1px solid #000"> <?php echo $k; ?> </tr><?php } else  {?><td style="border:1px solid #000"> <?php echo $k; ?></td><?php } ?>
            <?php $t++;}?>
          
       
    
</table>

Comment: Please check updated answer and let me know if you have any issue

Answer (score 1):

```
   <?php
echo '<table width="100%" border="1">';
    for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++)
    {
        $y=10;
        $y*=($i-1);
        echo '<tr>';
            for ($x=1; $x <=10; $x++) {
                if ($i==1) {
                    echo '<td>'.$x.'</td>';
                }else{
                    $y+=$x;
                    echo '<td>'.$y.'</td>';
                    if ($y==72) {
                        break;
                    }
                    $y-=$x;
                }

            }
        echo '</tr>';
    }
echo '</table>';
```

This will print the bellow table:
[image]

Comment: this is  what i need boss. thanks your entire stack team support

Comment: your answer is correct,but i need upto 72 column, after 50, 51,52....72 where i can change, please edit your answer

Comment: do you mean 5 rows which each row have 72 column?

Comment: that is not a problem, row may be 5 or 6 up it ends up 72 column, i change $i<=8 it goes up to 80 , i wanted you to stop at 72

Comment: can you upload an image from table what you want exactly?

Comment: see you are given correct answer, it's simple total i need 72 column, in each row i planned to give 10 column,

Comment: i  uploaded the image, it should stop at 72

Comment: do you want to create 72 cells (now 50 cells)?

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php $x = 10; if ($i % $x == 0) { ?>

      ....

 <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please check , not getting properly<?php
for($i=1; $i<=72; $i++)
{
$x = 10; 
if ($i % $x == 0) 
{ 
?>
<td width="100%">
<?php echo "Click Here to see Site No.'".$i."'. & Area sqft No" .$i;?>
</td>
<?
}
}
?>

Comment: <table width="100%">
<tr>
<?php
for($i=1; $i<=72; $i++)
{
$x = 10; 
if ($i % $x == 0) 
{ 
?>
<td><?php echo $i;?></td>
<?php
}
}
?>
</tr>
</table> , i am not getting the ouptut see the questiton please

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/21387534)

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting the question correct, why don't you do as below:

```
echo '<table>';
for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {
  echo '<tr>';
    for ($y=1; $y<=10; $y++) {
          echo '<td>Row_'.$i.' - Col_'.$y.'</td>';  
    }
  echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

It will print something like below:

[image]

Comment: great i have altered like this, but i need each column number like this 1 23456.........goest to up 72 column  check this <table width="100%" border="1">
<?php 
for($i=1; $i<=72; $i++) 
{
 ?>
    <tr>
    <?php
    for ($y=1; $y<=10; $y++) 
 {
  
  ?>
   <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>  
    <?php
    }
 ?>
  </tr>
  <?php
}
?>
</table>

Comment: In your code, you can use `$y` as your column number. You can put it like `<td><?php echo 'Row: '.$i. ' & Col: '.$y' ?></td>`. This will print both rows number and column number in each cell. Works?