# How to categorize data like pagination?

Tags: php, pagination

I want to create a simple list for the posts. I want to the posts in 10 by 10 posts, total posts is 50. I want to list it as categories.

**Example**
Let's assume, we have 55 posts in total:

- page 1 (10 posts)
- page 2 (10 posts)
- page 3 (10 posts)
- page 4 (10 posts)
- page 5 (5 posts)

For pages and products it will same as like posts list.

```
<?php
$total_posts = 30;
$total_pages = 100;
$total_products = 500;

// Example all total data
$data = '{"post":["post-1","post-2","post-3","post-4","post-5"],"page":["page-1","page-2","page-3","page-4","page-5"],"product":["product-1","product-2","product-3","product-4","product-5"]}';

$post_types = '{"post_types":["post","page","product"]}';
$post_types = json_decode($post_types);

foreach($post_types as $post_type_key => $post_type_value)
{
    foreach($post_type_value as $key => $value)
    {
        echo $value.'<br>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you simply asking how you can output a kind of "sub-heading" for every group of ten records ...? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17355652/1427878

Comment: No, I want to list the records like pagination. 10 posts = post and 11 to 20 posts = post-1 etc...

Comment: When doing `$post_types = json_decode('{"post_types":["post","page","product"]}');`, you would only loop once over `$post_types`, since its only item is `$post_types->post_types`. Furthermore, why not directly write `$post_types = (object)[ "post_types" => ["post","page","product"] ];`?

Answer (score 0):

I just solve my question.

```
<?php
// Your array of posts (assuming you have an array of 50 posts)
$totalPosts = 50;
$posts = range(1, $totalPosts); // Example array from 1 to 50

// Define the number of posts per category
$postsPerCategory = 10;

// Loop through the posts and categorize them
for ($category = 1; $category <= ceil($totalPosts / $postsPerCategory); $category++) {
    echo "<strong>Category {$category}:</strong><br>";

    // Calculate the start and end indexes for the current category
    $startIndex = ($category - 1) * $postsPerCategory;
    $endIndex = min($startIndex + $postsPerCategory - 1, $totalPosts - 1);

    // Display the posts in the current category
    for ($i = $startIndex; $i <= $endIndex; $i++) {
        echo "Post-{$posts[$i]} ";
    }

    echo "<br><br>";
}
?>
```